# Create users using Service Account with Google Admin SDK?

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

The documentation is a little unclear on this. Can I actually do this? The only examples I've seen so far are from the Google documentation that show it using the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow class to gain authorization. I've seen a few examples of using the Service Account to update and retrieve a list of users, but nothing for creating. Is this possible? If so, does anyone know of any examples floating around? I can't seem to find anything that addresses it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can follow the steps outlined in the following API docs page to create the service account and perform a domain wide delegation of authority, please bear in mind you need the email address of a domain administrator which the service account can act on their behalf:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

The page includes a Java example of how to instantiate a com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory object using the service account and private key created on the Google Developers Console. Then use the example I've provided in this answer to create the users:

[Create gmail account for a domain using Google Admin SDK Directory API in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383591/create-gmail-account-for-a-domain-using-google-admin-sdk-directory-api-in-java/25385870#25385870)

Comment: You're awesome! Everything I saw about the service accounts said that it wasn't used for accessing user data, so I wasn't sure how that would actually work for creating data. Thanks!