# Switching from username/password to OAuth 2 in Java application using Google Directory API

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-directory-api

I do the following in a java application to authenticate my client and multi-client.

```
  AppsForYourDomainClient client = null;
  ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient multiClient = null;
  try {
     client = new AppsForYourDomainClient("someUserName@email.com", "password", "email.com");

     multiClient = new ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient("someUserName@email.com", "password", "email.com","multidomain-api-sample-email.com");

  } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();   
  }
```

I want to switch to OAuth 2 authentication. Also AppsForYourDomainClient and ProvisioningApiMultiDomainSampleClient are being deprecated. How do I move forward with authenticating with OAuth2 and the new Google Directory API?

What I was needing was examples. There seems to be plenty of documentation but very little example.

Luckily I found this:
[Create gmail account for a domain using Google Admin SDK Directory API in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383591/create-gmail-account-for-a-domain-using-google-admin-sdk-directory-api-in-java)

Which points me in the right direction. And I hope if this post comes up on any searches, then they can refer to the link above.

Thanks

Comment: The obvious answer is read the docs. There are no real shortcuts. For example, your question doesn't state whether your Java app is on Android, installed on a PC, or running in a web service. The OAuth answer would be different for each scenario. You should also know that OAuth is *not* an authentication protocol, it's an authorization protocol. Sorry if it's not the answer you're looking for, but I'd be doing you a disservice to mislead you into thinking you can implement OAuth without fundamentally understanding it first. Start with https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading and understanding more but examples help far beyond reading. I have found one that points me in the right direction and I edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Be really careful. OAuth has so many variants, and is so misunderstood, that you can waste a lot of time chasing examples that turn out to be red herrings. Been there, seen it, got the t-shirt. The link I posted (with it's child links for the different scenarios) and the Oauth Playground are your best friends.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this link helps - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

There are a number of steps that need to be followed.  You will first need to create a project in Google Developer Console and go from there.