# How to Create And Access Gmail Account Details using Java APIs?

Tags: gmail-api

I want to create a gmail account using java APIs and also want to access the basic details of the existing gmail user. I tried a lot of sites but not able to write a code. help me with a code snippet

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/) shows, creation of Gmail account isn't an added feature yet for this API. Currently, you can use Gmail API to add Gmail features like:

- Read messages from Gmail
- Send email messages
- Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
- Search for specific messages and threads
- Create filters to automatically label, forward, or archive messages

So, if you wish to create a user account, an option that you can do is to use the [Users: insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) of Google Apps Admin SDK - Directory API. With the inclusion of the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing), you may send HTTP request using the following format:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

In the request body, supply user's resources with the available properties that are given in the documentation.

Likewise, you can access the basic details of an existing gmail user also with the use of [Directory API: User Accounts](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users). You can retrieve a user using the `GET` request and include also the authorization. Format is:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/userKey
```

- `userKey` can be the user's primary email address, the unique user id, or one of the user's alias email addresses.

If request is successful, this returns a JSON response with `HTTP 200 status code` and the properties for the user account.

For more information, please check the given documentations.

Lastly, to help you with the Java implementation, you may refer to the solution given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383591/create-gmail-account-for-a-domain-using-google-admin-sdk-directory-api-in-java).

Happy coding!